# Create a password protected MSI package with wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to create a password protected MSI package. So I first added a property,

```
<Property Id='INSTALL_PASSWORD' Value='' Secure='yes' />
```

I will instruct user to install the package like this

```
msiexec /i XX.msi INSTALL_PASSWORD=XXX
```

Now, how can I validate the password?

Comment: You can use a custom action to validate the password, but it is generally better to move things like this to the application launch sequence where validation codes and serials are easy to debug. That means a lot for quality and reliability.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [launch condition](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/launchconditions.html) to check if the property matches some value.

Alternatively, you could add an immediate [custom action](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html) taht validates the password and stops the installation if the password does not match.

But I think this all may be a bad idea, considering uninstall or upgrade scenarios for example. Wouldn't it be much easier just to zip your package with a password?

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an example XML?